# How can I install a debug build for coreutils?

Tags: apt, software-installation, coreutils

I am trying to install the debug build for coreutils package which is not available.
I also went through this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash) and followed all steps but I still can't see a debug package for coreutils on doing `apt-get policy coreutils`.

Is debug package for `coreutils` really available? If yes how can I download them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install any debug symbol which package is not included in the repositories in the form of `-dbg` package, you need to add a new repository as detailed in the [Debugging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash):

1. Add the repositories:

   ```
   echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse" | \
   sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
   echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
   sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
   ```
2. Add the GPG key:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 428D7C01
   ```
3. Update your package list:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install the debugging symbols package, in this case `coreutils-dbgsym`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install coreutils-dbgsym
   ```

Note that you will need to specify the same version, for that use `apt-cache policy package` and install it using `sudo apt-get install package-dbgsym=version`.